# How to get the current input value which is entering on select 2 input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When i'm first time entering multi select values i got the current entered text value based on below code in jquery

```
 <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select areas" style="width: 100%;" id="edit_areas" name="area">
 </select>
$(".select2-search__field").val()

$(document).on('keyup',".select2", function (e) {

    var city = $("#add_city option:selected").text();
    var location = $(".select2-search__field").val();});
```

which works fine.

But on edit when try to enter more values,current entering value is failed to get by using above code its showing empty

Note: Here i'm setting the dropdown dynamically based on user enters

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide you HTML, and complete Jquery code.

Comment: show the html code also

Comment: how you are setting the value for edit?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Here i'm setting the drop down dynamically based on user input and its working fine on create.but on edit of that form and trying to enter more values for multi select that input value is failed to fetch in jquery to set dynamic dropdown. Hope you understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use select2 specific methods to get and set the value, once you already converted to the select2.

When you are setting the value (e.g. for edit),  use code like following :

```
$(".select2").select2("val", "Am,WY".split(","));
```

and to get the value, use code like following :

```
$(".select2").select2('val');
```

Hope it will resolve your issue (as not sure what is the HTML and code you are having, its just a guess :-))

Comment: can you explain why you have used this one $(".select2").select2("val", "Am,WY".split(","));

Comment: this is to set the value, `.split()` used to set multiple values.

Comment: Prashant i was getting fallowing error when i try to get the value --The select2('val') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.

Comment: As mentioned in answer, these method works on elements which are already converted to `select2`. Better you share the fiddle here!

Comment: Prashant by using this $(".select2").select2('val'); i was getting already selected value but i want to get user currently entering on keyup function
for this i used $('.select2 input[type=search]').select2('val'); its showing as undefined

Comment: check this fiddle. It will give the value on next keypress once user has selected and the value got added as token (not just by typing one or two characters!
http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/fyhsz9ra/1284/

Comment: your solution is works for first time when i created the form and when i try to edit the details and enter more values to that multiselect its not displaying that input value

Comment: Please add fiddle here!

Comment: there are no options in select so no value to select! Dont know what exactly you are targeting but if you want a character just typed you can get it by `$(this).find(".select2-input").val();`

Comment: Prashant here i was setting dynamic dropdown based on user input.Hope you got  what exactly why here i'm not displaying options

Comment: That is understood. But after setting it what you want on keyup?

Comment: As it is multiselect dropdown each time i was setting new dropdown list based on input value.

Comment: $(this).find(".select2-input").val(); this works fine as i need to destroy the dropdown every time.On edit i need to destroy the dropdown after destroying it i was able to get the value. Thanks for your continues support

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML or complete jQuery it's hard to see exactly what you are trying to do. So I have made a stab in the dark.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mrselect').on('change', function() {
    var values = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var fancyPantsArray = [];
    values.each(function() {
      fancyPantsArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(fancyPantsArray);
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="mrselect" multiple="multiple" name="mrselect">
  <option value="Mr Option 1">Mr Option 1</option>
  <option value="Mr Option 2">Mr Option 2</option>
  <option value="Mr Option 3">Mr Option 3</option>
  <option value="Mr Option 4">Mr Option 4</option>
  <option value="Mr Option 5">Mr Option 5</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here i'm setting the dropdown dynamically based on user enters and i updated my question can you please look into once.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```js
var nome = $("#select_id").data('select').$dropdown.find("input").val();


or 



$('input.select2-input').val();
```

Comment: Both the solutions are not working can you please look into question once.