# How to get current input value which is entered in select2 input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I was trying to set the multi-select dropdown dynamically for select2 plugin based user entered key

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select areas" style="width: 100%;" id="add_area" name="area">
```

I got the value based on fallowing in jquery

```
$(".select2-search__field").val()
```

After when i try to edit that form and enter more values to select2  I was unable to fetch the value which user enter in select2

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select areas" style="width: 100%;" id="edit_areas" name="area">
```

to get the value in jquery I used

```
$(".select2-search__field").val()
```

Here its showing as empty value.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?Hope my question is clear to you.

Comment: please provide code snippet or jsfilldle

Comment: That's a very strange selector. Also, assuming there are multiple elements with the same class, `$(".select2-search__field")` will return more than 1 element.

Comment: Where is the element with `select2-search__field` class?

Comment: select2-search__field is in inspect elements at select2 plugin input value class

Comment: @satya, you should edit the question, rather posting same question again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307427/how-to-get-the-current-input-value-which-is-entering-on-select-2-input-field/44307804?noredirect=1#comment75623699_44307804